# Dict equivalency in python

Tags: python, dictionary, equivalence

I'd like to find out how dictionary equivalence is checked in python, depending on whether the same dictionary instance is used, or a different instance with the same values. I've found some stackoverflow posts hinting at the answer, but none stating it explicitely.

Basically, assuming I have an array of dictionaries, with various key/value pairs. If I now created a new instance of a dictionary, and performed an `mydict in mylist` check, when would the result of this check be True, and when would it be False?

Optimally, I'd hope that the behavior is as follows:

|  | Same instance | Different instance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Same value** | T | T |
| **Different value** | F | F |

However, it looks like the real result is something more like this:

|  | Same instance | Different instance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Same value** | T | T |
| **Different value** | T | F |

Is my second result guaranteed to always be the case? How does equivalence of dicts work exactly, in Python?

Also, what is the best way to check if a dict is in a list anyway? With the following code:

```
 if b not in last[a]:
     last[a][b] = [] #Since this happens in a for loop, just make sure the array is initialized
 newIni = {"val1": val1, "val2": val2}
 if newIni not in last[a][b]:
     # do stuff
```

Gives me the error `unhashable type dict`, which supposedly should only come up when trying to use dicts as a key, but here I'm using dicts as a value, so not sure what's going on...

Comment: How can you have Same Instance *and* Different Value?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: What is `a` and what is `b` in your code snippet?

Comment: @Daweo Just some string values.